# Should I ignore this warning? (React)

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code;

```
const updateMonsters = useCallback(() => {
    setMonsterObjects((prevMonsters) => 
        prevMonsters.map(({orientation, pos, walkingState, type}) => {
            const [offsetLeft, offsetTop] = orientationFactorMap[orientation];
            const nextCoordinates = [pos[0] + offsetLeft, pos[1] + offsetTop];
            const isValidPosition = isNewPositionValid(nextCoordinates, invalidPositions);
            const nextOrientation = isValidPosition ? orientation : oppositeOrientationMap[orientation];
            const nextWalkingState = isValidPosition ? walkingState + 2 : 2;
            const nextPos = isValidPosition ? nextCoordinates : [pos[0] - offsetLeft, pos[1] - offsetTop];
            return {
                orientation: nextOrientation,
                walkingState: nextWalkingState,
                pos: nextPos,
                type
            }
        })
    );
}, [invalidPositions]); //Dep will never change. 

const updatePlayerStatus = useCallback(() => {
    setPlayerHealth((prevHealth) => 
        didMonsterTouchDog(dogObject.pos, monsterObjects.map(({pos}) => pos)) ? prevHealth - 1 : prevHealth
    )
}, [dogObject.pos, monsterObjects, setPlayerHealth]); // Dep WILL always change. 

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(1);
    const timeout = setInterval(() => {
        updateMonsters();
        updatePlayerStatus();
    }, 500);
    return () => clearInterval(timeout);
}, [updateMonsters, updatePlayerStatus])
```

My intention is to run updateMonsters() while the component is loaded. Alone, there are no issues. The problem begins when I try to add updatePlayerStatus(). Since dogObject.pos/monsterObjects changes, whenever it does change it triggers useEffect again. It *works* as I expect if I don't add them as dependencies, but throws a warning at me.

```
./src/components/Level.js
  Line 93:8:  React Hook useCallback has missing dependencies: 'dogObject.pos' and 'monsterObjects'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Edit: DogObject:

```
const [dogObject, setDogObject] = useState({
    pos: dog.initialPosition,
    orientation: dog.initialOrientation,
    walkingState: 2
})
```

Comment: No, you shouldn't. Warnings aren't put there to be ignored.

Comment: Where and how do you define `dogObject`?

Comment: Edited @norbitrial

Comment: @S.S.Anne But what's my alternative? My intended outcome clashes with the behavior of useEffect.

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience in this area. I just know that across the board, it's not a good idea to ignore warnings.